# VB.NET: Convert a date dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert a dd/mm/yy date to dd/mm/yyyy automatically. 
**Example:** if I insert in the textbox "12/01/90", the program should automatically convert the text to "12/01/1990" or "01/01/20" to "01/01/2020".

Also, I should check the date to make sure it is correct.
**Example:** if I enter "80/70/2000" it must give me an error because the date does not exist. How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2), then [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the input as a string, you would first parse it into a date with the format specifier, and then convert it back into a string.

```
Dim input as String = "22/03/19" ' dd/mm/yy
Dim dt as DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
If (DateTime.TryParseExact(input,
                            "dd/MM/yy",
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                            dt
)) Then
    Dim output as String = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Console.WriteLine(output)
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error")
end if
```

Output:

> 22/03/2019

You can try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uRZYIt)

Comment: For the record, casting doesn't change the type of the object, so that's not a cast, but rather a conversion.  A cast would be if you already had a `Date` value but assigned to an `Object` variable.

Comment: @jmcilhinney fixed